# how do i make an installer with several applications packed and installed together in start-menu (like Microsoft does)

Tags: wpf, clickonce

I'm making a wpf application that launches and installs several other apps like [example image from google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8uurd.jpg).

It should look like Microsoft Office programs when installed [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IL8vF.png)

So I have made a test-application and published it using clickOnce, and it works perfectly fine and even makes the Start-Menu folder and all, but I could not find a way to add more apps inside the folder, or Group install them. All the sample apps I published have their own folder in the Start-Menu folder.

Do I do something else in the **Publish** section in the **Properties** menu?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found someone saying this 
"Set the Publisher Name to the same for all your application, and they'll all appear in a subfolder on the start menu."